# Difference between bacterial chlorophylls

Tags: bacteriology, photosynthesis, pigmentation

I understand that bacterial chlorophylls are of the form a, b, c and d. 
But i read in my textbook about pigments like bacterio purpurin and bacterio viridin; are they a part of the 4 types of chlorophylls and if not how are they different and what actually are they?

Comment: What research have you done before asking it here?

Comment: @another 'Homo sapien'  i looked through a couple pages on the internet about bacterial photosynthetic pigments along with a wikipedia page and also a couple books but none of them were very clear about the relationship between bacterio purpurin/viridin and bacterio chlorophylls.  Thus,  my question is simply to ask for the relationship between them and if someone could explain the difference between

Comment: Thanks for the question... me too unfamiliar with the term "bacterio-purpurin", however only recall the term "bacterio-viridin" in my old middle-school textbooks in context of photosynthetic pigments. I can't recall I've seen the terms anywhere else. Maybe they are obsoleted terms now replaced by some other terms. I'm not seeing these 2 terms in wikipedia, too.

Answer (score 3):

From A search in [Pubchem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov) database, in [substances](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/) for [bacterioviridin](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/135358783#section=Depositor-Supplied-Synonyms), it seems just another synonym for bacteriochlorophyll-C.

[image: Screenshot with synonymy].

The incomplete page do not show any image-entry. From another entry about bacteriochlorophyll-C, I've took the following image:

[image: Bacteriochlorophyll-C]
Bacteriochlorophyll-C; which is being told same as Bacterioviridin

...............................................

...............................................

From similar search on same website for [bacteriopurpurin](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pcsubstance?term=Bacteriopurpurin), it shows,

- 1. [Bacteriopurpurin](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/273548625#section=Top)

[image: Bacteriopurpurin-a xanthophyll compound according to pubchem]

is a Xanthophyll compound; with another similar entry [Bacteriopurpurin](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/249936575#section=2D-Structure)

It is also being called [Hydroxyspirilloxanthin](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/5366504)

....................................

- 2. Another search reslult, [Bacteriopurpurin 18](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/275834801),

shows this photo:

[image: Bacteriopurpurine-18 is a porphyrine compound according to Pubchem]

Which is clearly a porphyrin-type compound (With smaller 4 pyrrole-type rings) with nitrogen (N) atoms.

......................................

......................................

Though you have not mentioned in the original question, another such old term is Chlorobium-chlorophyll. When [searched](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pcsubstance/?term=Chlorobium%20Chlorophyll) ;  there i could found [one entry](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/135350585) in the PubChem database, about chlorobium chlorophyll; which tells; it is same as bacteriochlorophyll-D, though the incomplete page does not display any structure.

From [some other entry](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/96024378) about bacteriochlorophyll-d; the structure given here:

[image: Bacteriochlorophyll-D]
Bacteriochlorophyll-D, which is being told same as chlorobium chlorophyll. Look this has a little bit different structure from bacteriochlorophyll-C (bacterioviridin according to pubchem) , because chlorophyll-D (this) is lacking a methyl group at left hand middle side of the photo.

................................................

However, I cannot ensure they are free from nomenclatural conflicts. IMO it is better to use modern terms like bacteriochlorophyll-a, b, c, d, e, f and g.

................................................

> **Reference:** The PubChem Project by NCBI
>
> - [image: The Pubchem Project]

.....................................

**N.B. :**

**To quickly find differences among some main types of chlorophylls and bacteriochlorophylls**; I've attached the following diagram. Most of the pictures are taken from PubChem; two I couldn't found in Pubchem, so I took them from a PMC articles. All are linked below the diagram.

[image: Comparisons among chlorophylls and bacteriochlorophylls]
Comparisons among some chlorophylls and bacteriochlorophylls.

Sources:

- Chlorophyll-A : [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/8143841#section=2D-Structure), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophyll_a) .
- Chlorophyll-B : [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/316426349#section=2D-Structure), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophyll_b) .
- Chlorophyll-C1 : [Pubchem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/319412522#section=2D-Structure) (PubChem also tells as "Chlorophyllide C1") .
- Chlorophyll-C2 : [Pubchem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/319412568#section=2D-Structure) (PubChem also tells as "Chlorophyllide C2") .
- Chlorophyll-C (C1, C2, etc): [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophyll_c) .
- Chlorophyll-D : [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/312238856#section=2D-Structure), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophyll_d)  .
- Chlorophyll-E: No records seen.
- Chlorophyll-F: [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/319884407#section=2D-Structure) .
- Chlorophyll-F **'** : [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/122706135#section=2D-Structure) .
- Bacteriochlorophyll-A :  [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/13420#section=Top) .
- Bacteriochlorophyll-B : [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/312237631#section=Top) .
- Bacteriochlorophyll-C : [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/96024379#section=Top) ([Bacterioviridin](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/135358783#section=Depositor-Supplied-Synonyms)) .
- Bacteriochlorophyll-D : [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/96024378#section=2D-Structure) ([Chlorobium chlorophyll](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/135350585#section=Depositor-Supplied-Synonyms)) .
- Bacteriochlorophyll-E<sub>F</sub> : [A PMC article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3415949/)  `*` .
- Bacteriochlorophyll-F<sub>F</sub> : [same PMC article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3415949/)  `*` .
- Bacteriochlorophyll-G : [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/substance/57393955#section=2D-Structure) .

The PMC Article `*` : Bacteriochlorophyll f: properties of chlorosomes containing the “forbidden chlorophyll”, by Vogl, Tank, Orf, Blankenship, Bryant.

.....................................

Comment: thanks for taking the time to go through pubchem,  but as it seems bacterio purpurin is still doubtful and do you have any idea about a similarity between chlorobium chlorophyll and bacterio viridin,  are they synonymous?

Comment: Not showing synonymous. I've started already adding info about chlorobium chlorophyll

Comment: @AnamikaGhosh Thanks very much for asking the question... otherwise the fact behind some mysterious terms would remain unknown to me.

Comment: So, what's the conclusion here? Is bacteriopurpurin a type of bacteriochlorophyll?

Comment: According to the PubChem entry Bacteriopurpurin can't be a chlorophyll. It has a different structure.